# How to start vagrant/heroku

Tags: python, heroku, vagrant, vagrantfile

I found a article online that explains how to connect vagrant to heroku, so I would be able to deploy my applications online. I got to step 4 in the article, but I got an error when I tired to install foreman (gem install foreman). How can I get it to install. Does any one used vagrant and heroku before and can they explain how they got it to work. The picture of the error is at the bottom and here is a link of the article: https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud330/deploy.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a permission issue with the path `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn`

You can try one of the following

1) Use `chmod` to grant write permission to the location  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

or

2) Rerun your command with `sudo`

Comment: thanks but when i fix the problem I got to another one. Each time I type in python app.py. bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `__git_ps1)'

Comment: It is important to keep a question on a single issue. If my answer has helped to resolve this question, please accept. Then open a new question for the bash exception with full stacktrace and other relevant info.

Comment: Cool. Remember to click on the 'tick' icon to accept the answer.